# What's the difference between Rank 1 through Rank 3 investigators?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I really don't see a difference between investigators of different ranks, whether it's power, personality, weapon type/weapon shape, or knowledge.

Would you please describe the concept of ranks to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, investigators of different ranks hold different weapons and have more skill in fighting. The rank determines an Investigators' level of responsibility in the CCG, access to high-risk missions and high-rated targets. In addition, the rank also determines the salary of the investigator and it also shows different factors of experience they may have gone through.

There are two types of investigators:

- Junior Rank Investigator
- Senior Rank investigator

Junior Ranks have 3 stages in their careers:

- Rank 3: Ghoul investigators here have a special case in their career, and are made investigators without any formal training in the academy.
- Rank 2: Everybody without the special cases start here after graduating the academy.
- Rank 1: Your highest rank as a Junior Investigator. You've seen some stuff, you've been through the fieldwork, but your still not at the peak of your career.

Now we move on to the Senior Investigators. There are once again three types.

- First Class Investigators:

  The lowest rank to be considered a Senior Rank Investigator. Most investigators reach this rank later in their careers. Senior Rank Investigators are responsible for training a junior rank investigator. It is basically very difficult to move up the ladder from here on.
- Associate Special Class:

  This rank is the second highest rank and it is achieved by a small percent of First Class investigators. Responsibilities include overseeing wards as necessary.
- Special Class:

  This rank is the highest rank. Typically, they are the strongest of all investigators. These guys command operations and will oversee their wards daily as part of their responsibility.

For example, Kureo Mado has something called a Quinque weapon. It's like the spine petal thing. Kureo is a first class investigator. Kureo is very experienced and takes Koutarou Amon as his partner.

*Reference: [**Ghoul Investigator**](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoul_Investigator)*